# "&minus" instead of "-" in TextView which setting text from JSON

Tags: java, android, json, textview, retrofit2

I have weather app, which is get weather information json from here:

http://icomms.ru/inf/meteo.php/?tid=44

There's a minus in `"temp"` value (for ex. : `"temp":"−16"`), and when I get value from json with retrofit2 and show it in textview it shows `&minus;16` instead of `-16`

[image: Screenshot]

How I can show `-16` instead of `&minus;16`?

Fragment from RecyclerViewAdapter (I use it to show weather info for multiply days), where I set text to textview

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Meteo meteo = data.get(position);
        holder.date.setText(meteo.date);
        holder.tod.setText(meteo.tod);
        holder.pressure.setText(meteo.pressure);

        // THIS IS TEMPERATURE SETTING TEXT LINE
        holder.temp.setText(meteo.temp);

        holder.humidity.setText(meteo.humidity);
        holder.wind.setText(meteo.wind);
        holder.cloud.setText(meteo.cloud);
}
```

Weather data class:

```
public class Meteo {
    public String date;
    public String tod;
    public String pressure;
    public String temp;
    public String humidity;
    public String wind;
    public String cloud;
}
```

Response body:

```
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(APIService.HOST)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory
                    .create())
            .build();

    APIService apiService = retrofit.create(APIService.class);

    Call<List<Meteo>> call = apiService.getMeteo(44);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Meteo>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Meteo>> call, Response<List<Meteo>> response) {
            MeteoAdapter adapter = new MeteoAdapter(response.body());
            // Method show just shows list of weather data
            getViewState().show(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Meteo>> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("MyLog", "WRONG");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. I use it for formatting html tags in a textview:

```
String s = Html.fromHtml("&minus;16");
tv.setText(s);
```

Reasoning: It sets the text as a Spanned object, rather than a string.

Note: Cannot test this currently, sorry if it doesnt work.